# Cambiarle el tamaño a un label html

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un label y quiero que no este tan junto con otras cosas.

El label lo tengo así:

```
<label id="labelSoliReag" for="file">Solicitudes Reasignadas <br /><progress id="file" max="100" value="70">70%</progress></label>
```

Dentro de un H3, que es Solicitud.

Adjunto foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar el tamaño de la barra y su distancia respecto a otros elementos usando las propiedades width y margin de css

```
progress{
   width: 100px; /*más ancho*/
   margin: 20px; /*separación de otros elementos*/
}
```

si lo prefieres, puedes usar margin-top/margin-left/margin-bottom/margin-right para establecer el margen en solo uno de los lados del elemento